# how to delete from expo requestLegacyExternalStorage permission

Tags: react-native, google-play-console, expo

how to remove requestLegacyExternalStorage permission and background location for google play

Answer (score 1):

Expo and React Native modules include some permissions by default.

If your app does not require those permissions just add: `android.permissions: []` in your `app.json` file. Just like that:

```js
"android": {
  "permissions": [],
  // ...
}
```

If some feature in your app do need some permissions, check here which one you shoud add: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions

Another useful tip: try [upgrading your expo](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/) to tha latest SDK. After SDK 40, some permissions became opt-in instead of opt-out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Android developer release, storage updates in Android 11 giving better protection to app and user data on external storage.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

After updating your app to SDK 41 to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag and nothing have to do, just ignore this warning.

> For SDK 40 and under (before targeting Android 11), Expo includes
> requestLegacyExternalStorage in the AndroidManifest in order to opt
> out of those storage changes, as suggested by Google documentation.
>
> For SDK 41 and above (after targeting Android 11), Expo updated
> libraries to account for these storage changes, as suggested by
> Google documentation and still include requestLegacyExternalStorage,
> since as Google states in their documentation.

If there is no possibility of an update, the solution is to remove MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission from your app's manifest in order to successfully publish your app.